# MS Graph create subscription returns ExtensionError and ServiceUnavailable

Tags: email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

API : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions

```
payload : 
{
   "changeType": "created,updated",
   "notificationUrl": "https://example.com/api/notification",
   "resource": "me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
   "expirationDateTime":"2024-01-06T18:00:22.645Z",
   "clientState": "secretClientValue",
   "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}`

error response :
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ExtensionError",
        "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: ServiceUnavailable; Reason: Target resource '00034001-6082-882a-0000-000000000000' hosted on database '5efc9825-cf17-4cf8-ac21-55a2dc9833eb' is currently on backend 'Unknown']",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-01-04T13:56:33",
            "request-id": "a260ba00-c45e-4228-89c7-0a7d123767f2",
            "client-request-id": "a260ba00-c45e-4228-89c7-0a7d123767f2"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to hit API through Postman to create subscription of MS graph outlook mail.
I explore more thing but not found why it is giving this error.

If you have any solution and fix problem please reply.

For you reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http